# Managed or crawled property not generated

Tags: search, content-type, metadata, managed-property, crawled-property

In SP 2013 on-prem, I have created 2 site columns with XML - declarations. 1 of the columns automatically generate a crawled and managed property, but the other does not. I can not understand for the life of me why they are not generated for the last one.

This is the field that get generated properties in Search schema

```
<Field  ID="{E4GC3538-F6BG-5E988-B997-1E101GDC1G2F}"
              StaticName="xxx_Ingress"
              Name="xxx_Ingress"
              DisplayName="Ingress"
              Group="XXX"
              Type="Note"
              EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"
              Indexed="FALSE"
              Required="FALSE"
              NumLines="6"
              RichText="FALSE"
              Sortable="FALSE"
              RestrictedMode="TRUE"
              RichTextMode="Compatible"
              IsolateStyles="FALSE"
              AppendOnly="FALSE"
              UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE">
      </Field>
```

This doesn't

```
      <Field    ID="{1497E8F7-7G7D-5716-9D5G-53FDE2510117}"
                StaticName="xxx_plassering"
                Name="xxx_plassering"
                DisplayName="Plassering"
                Group="XXX"
                Type="Number"
                Required="FALSE"
                EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"
                Indexed="FALSE"
                Min="1"
                Max="1000"
                Decimals="0">
      </Field>
```

Please advice.

Comment: Do they belong to the same CT? Do you ave at least one list item defining a value for the `xxx_plassering` field?

Comment: They do not belong to the same ct, and yes, i have many items that has value for the column xxx_plassering. I have also run full crawl several times.